# Find a reference for a string data reference in Ida Pro

Tags: dll, reverse-engineering, ida

I would like to hack a dll.

My dll return an error message ( a return, and not a MessageBox).
I opened my dll in ida Pro.

I find my string data reference but i don't find xrefs from. When i try to find xrefs from i have the "Couldn't find any xrefs".

Anyone could help me please ? How finding reference please ? I would like to find the test which return this string in order to patch this dll. It's an ODBC Driver.

[image]
[image]
[image]

It's for a hack, not a crack ;)
I have the licence but i would like to change restriction in the odbc driver (the dll ).

Thanks a lot,

Answer (score 3):

The string is probably referenced through an array of strings (the 3rd screenshot is probably this array). This would translate to something like this in assembly:

```
lea eax, StringArray ; load base of string array
mov ecx, StringIndex ; get string index in array

mov eax, [eax+ecx*4] ; eax (dest) = pointer to string
```

You probably just need to go up to the start of the string array to find a reference (reference to the first string on the array, hence a ref the array itself).